# How to add inside the container view IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subview, uicontainerview

I'm new new to IOS. I have created container view which contain 2 view controller(ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB). I have added button and create action for that in ViewControllerA but which is not working(It's not clickable). Can we create button inside ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB?. How to fix this?.

```
self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: How do u added `ViewControllerA` ?

Comment: select the button and check if user interaction enabled is checked in IB

Comment: yes, i checked that which is enabled. but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct. Can you check the `self.view.frame` Maybe it is coming like you expected. Inside which method are you setting the frame ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's not working. I added the above code in the ContainerviewController  segue.